# Sound generation or sound file concatenation in PHP

Tags: php, audio, procedural

Is it possible to generate sound using PHP - or is there support for sound file concatenation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/create-an-audio-stitching-tool-in-php/5810215) audio stitching solution for Php.

OR

[ffmpeg-php](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/) library